# GitHubのローカルリポジトリの使い方

Tags: git, github, svn

非常に初歩的な質問で恐縮なのですがGitHub（Git）のローカルリポジトリの使い方について教えてください．
会社では2種類のバージョン管理システムを使っています．一つはメインのSubversionです．しかし最近GitHubも使用するようになってきました．私はGitHubはGitHub For Windowsを使用していて、たまにヘルプを見ながらGit Shellでコマンドラインを打っているレベルとお考えください．

わからない点はGitHub（Git）のSubversionと比べての使い方です．

- Subversionはリポジトリのどの階層でもローカルに作業コピーとして持ってこれます．このため、リポジトリにいろいろ入っていても、自分の対象のプログラムフォルダや文書フォルダだけ持ってきて作業できます．
- Gitは簡単にローカルリポジトリを作れますが、その中の特定のフォルダで作業するということが出来ないように思えます．例えば私はDITA Open Toolkitのプラグインを作っていますが、この作業を行うためには、常にローカルリポジトリの目的のフォルダから、DITA Open Toolkitのpluginsフォルダにコピーしなければなりません．つまりローカルリポジトリを直接の作業場所にすることがどうしてもできないのです．
- このため、直接の作業フォルダでプログラムに変更を加えたら、それをローカルリポジトリにコピーして、リモートにプッシュする．また別のPCで作業するときは、リモートとそのPCのローカルリポジトリを同期させて、そこからまた（そのPCの）直接の作業フォルダにコピーするという作業をやっています．
- Subversionの時は直接の作業フォルダ＝＝作業コピーとすることができましたので、作業を始めるときはTortoiseSVNでUpdateを行い、作業終了時にCommitすれば良かったので作業は簡単でした．でも私のGitHub（Git）の使い方では常にフォルダのコピーが伴い、そうはいかないように思えます．ある意味常にコピーし忘れや上書きの危険が付きまとうように思えます．

私の知識不足なのですが、GitHub（Git）でもっと効率的で安全に作業できるようにする方法はありませんでしょうか？

以上 よろしくお願いいたします．

※ なおこの質問は他のQ&Aサイトに数年前にポストしたのですがレスが付かなかったものです．もう時効と考えクロスポストさせていただきました．

Comment: `git clone`したフォルダ(のファイル)で作業するのが困難と考えている理由は何でしょうか?(`svn checkout`したフォルダ(のファイル)で作業するのと大差はないと思います)  それを追記すると回答が得られやすくなると思います。

Comment: 例えば（会社のリポジトリで恐縮ですが）、https://github.com/AntennaHouse/pdf5-ml が一例です．README.MDはあるし、サンプルフォルダもドキュメントもあります．ところが一番大切なのは、プラグインの`com.antennahouse.pdf5.ml`フォルダで、これはDITA Open Toolkitのpluginsフォルダに入れなければテストもデバッグもできません．しかし、ローカルリポジトリをまるごとpluginsフォルダに入れると他のフォルダ、ファイルが邪魔になります．というかそもそもあってはToolkitが動かなくなりかねず困ります．特殊かもしれませんが事情はこんなところです．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

シンボリックリンクを使うのが簡便かつ柔軟で、十分な解決策だと思いますが、[Sparse checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree#_sparse_checkout) という物があるようなので紹介しておきます。
これを使うと、指定したディレクトリのみを Git 配下に pull できます。
以下はコメントで示されているリポジトリのサブディレクトリを扱う例です。
参考: [git sparse checkout で一部のサブディレクトリだけを clone せずに pull/checkout する](https://mseeeen.msen.jp/git-sparse-checkout/)

```sh
git init
git config core.sparsecheckout true
git remote add origin 'git@github.com:AntennaHouse/pdf5-ml.git'
mkdir .git/info
echo com.antennahouse.pdf5.ml > .git/info/sparse-checkout
git pull origin master

ls -A
#=> com.antennahouse.pdf5.ml  .git
```

指定のディレクトリ以外を無視させる `.gitignore` が必要になるかも知れません。

```
/*
!/com.antennahouse.pdf5.ml/
```

Comment: `git init`をやっているので、`mkdir .git/info`は不要のようです．`pull`でリモートから着々と落としているのがわかるのですが、最終的に`error: Sparse checkout leaves no entry on working directory`になってしまいます．.git/info/sparse-checkoutにはちゃんと"com.antennahouse.pdf5.ml"が書き込まれています．オペミスでしょうか？（当方Windowsでして、GitHub For Windowsのコマンドラインシェルでやっています）

Comment: @tmakita `.git/info/sparse-checkout` に関し以下3点、試してみて下さい。
1. 余分なスペースなどが含まれていないかチェックする
2. 改行コードがLFでなければ、LFにしてみる
3. 指定しているディレクトリ名の末尾に `/` を追加してみる
（私のテスト環境は git version 2.14.1 です）

Comment: 失礼しました．.git/info/sparse-checkoutのエンコーディングの問題だったようです．例にあるプラグインのフォルダをちゃんと落とすことができました．確認ですが、このやり方だとplugins/.gitができ、plugins/com.anten‌​nahouse.pdf5.mlフォルダができます．つまりpluginsフォルダは１つのローカルリポジトリを形成していて、他のリポジトリとは共存できないということになりますね？実はpluginsフォルダには様々なプラグインが存在していて、各々GitHubにリポジトリを持っているのです．

Comment: @tmakita そうですね。やはり、実際的な作業でお勧めなのは、シンボリックリンクを使うことです。

Comment: ありがとうございました．大変勉強になりました．恥ずかしながらWindowsでシンボリックリンクが使えるのを知らなかったので試してみます．

Comment: シンボリックリンクで問題なく動作しました．